# Кеширование в PHP

Tags: кэширование, php

Подскажите, есть ли какой-нибудь удобный фреймворк для кеширования в ПХП помимо Zend?
А то писать свой механизм кеширования как-то слишком долго.
Спасибо.

Comment: Вам нужно кэширование или среда разработки?


Класс кэширования привел здесь: hashcode.ru/questions/77582/кэширование-простой-класс

Comment: Ок, спасибо, думаю что на первое время - то, что нужно.